# Reduce 3D volume mask by uniform margin in python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I'm working with 3D boolean arrays that mask a volume. My goal is to take a mask and reduce the area of the mask by some margin, m, in all dimensions.

Is there an easy way to do this using some common libraries (numpy, scipy, pandas, etc..)?

[I found some code online](http://www.siafoo.net/snippet/82) that uses multiple for loops to expand a mask by one dimension. This works for the expansion case but I feel like there is a more compact way out there.

Here is a minimum example of what I am looking for in 2D.

Original

```
array([[0., 0., 1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 1., 1., 0.],
       [1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
       [0., 1., 1., 1., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1., 0., 0.]])
```

Uniform reduction by 1 pixel

```
array([[0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 1., 1., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]])
```

But I want this to be in 3D space. Thank you for any input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be looking for [`scipy.ndimage.binary_erosion(a)`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.binary_erosion.html#scipy.ndimage.binary_erosion):

```
a = np.array([
    [0., 0., 1., 0., 0.],
    [0., 1., 1., 1., 0.],
    [1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
    [0., 1., 1., 1., 0.],
    [0., 0., 1., 0., 0.]
])
b = scipy.ndimage.binary_erosion(a)  # returns an array of bool
```

Note that this will erode internal surfaces too

Comment: Thanks for the edit.  I was distracted by your answer and checking it out (-:

Comment: Yeah, I'm bowing out.  This is too spot on.  Thanks for teaching me something today.

Comment: Great answer! Erosion was the mathematics I was looking for. `binary_erosion` worked perfectly for my problem.